# Spring Boot Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am facing this error:

[image]

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Here is how I am loading **css**. Note that I am not using `WebMvcConfigurer`.

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Material Design Bootstrap</title>
   <!-- Font Awesome -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}">
   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">
   <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/mdb.min.css}">
   <!-- Your custom styles (optional) -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/style.css}">
</head>
```

And I am loading **js** files at the end of the page (body).

```
   <body>

    ......      

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/popper.min.js" th:src="@{/js/popper.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/mdb.min.js" th:src="@{/js/mdb.min.js}"></script>
 </body>
```

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

Here is my directory structure

[image]

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Comment: @DforTye I have added directory structure. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are doing mistake while you are loading `jquery`. Your jquery is `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` but you are loading `jquery-3.1.1.min.js`

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js}"></script>
```

So check jquery version.

Comment: Oh man you got it right. Such a silly mistake. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me.

this is how my files are like in the static folder: [image]

this is how i include the files from the static folder into my html pages:[image]

i get rid of the static folder in the path since the server i guess knows to look for static content in the static folder. so the path for my all.min.css will be.

http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/demo/all.min.css

it will search for in the static folder.

if you add static i.e

> {link href="/static/vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"}

the server will look for

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/static/js/demo/all.min.css

and it won't get that path

remember to allow the routes in antmatchers if you're using spring security. see attached image

allow the routes to the folders in static folder if using spring security:[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: directory structure]

**Load css**

```
<link href="../static/assets/css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css"
    rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/assets/css/materialize.min.css}"
    media="screen,projection">
```

**Load js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/assets/js/materialize.min.js"
    th:src="@{/assets/js/materialize.min.js}"></script>
```

Comment: I have added my directory structure. Please have a look.